# Update cell based on two values for finding the row and column and corresponding worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Any ideas how I can carry out the following using VBA:

```
'Input a Value INTO Cell = [P4]'
'in Worksheet Titled = [P3] '
'WHERE ROW = [M4] AND Column = [N4]'
```

Basically when I click a button I want the formula that is in [Cell:P4] to be populated into another worksheet based on that worksheet having the title of [Cell:P3] and only in the Row and column where both the row has a number as stated in [Cell:M4] and the column has a number as stated in [Cell:N4].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first you need to know how to hook up your macro to a button. See [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/assign-a-macro-to-a-form-or-a-control-button-d58edd7d-cb04-4964-bead-9c72c843a283) official documentation or [this](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/macro-buttons/) one from excelcampus.com.
Basically, create a rectangle or any form you want your button to have, then right-click the form and click on "assign macro...". There are other more complicated ways, but this should be enough.

So now about the macro itself I will give you a few hints.
You want to copy a formula into another cell. The basic approach in VBA:

```
Sub copyFormula()
    Cells(1, 3).Formula = Cells(1, 2).Formula 'this will copy the formula in B1 to C1
End Sub
```

But we want to make this code a little safer. Lets write code that identifies the workbook and the worksheets that are involved.

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyFormula()
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws_source As Worksheet
Dim ws_target As Worksheet

Set ws_source = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'replace Sheet1 with name of your sheet
Set ws_target = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2") 'replace Sheet2 with name of your sheet

    ws_target.Cells(1, 3).Formula = ws_source.Cells(1, 2).Formula
End Sub
```

At this point you will need to worry about references in your formula (I am talking about the excel formula now, not the VBA code). Hint: Try using $ signs to lock cell references (not an immediate concern for this method) and also reference the sheet of the cell you are pointing to like this: "=Sheet2!A1"

Okay, now lets modify the code a little more. You want to address the sheet that has a variable name, namely the name that is written in Cell P3 (I assume of the source worksheet). We can do this.
All we have to do is read the value of P3 and then replace our static "Sheet2" in the target worksheet definition with said variable.

```
Dim targetName As String
targetName = ws_source.Cells(3, "P").Value    
Set ws_target = wb.Worksheets(targetName)
```

Try writing an invalid name into cell P3 and you will see why this is dangerous business as it is. I will leave it to you to take precautions that the entered value in P3 will not break your code :)

I do not really understand what you mean with the last part talking about rows and columns. Show us what you have tried, then we can help improve your code.

Answer (score -1):

Was this what you had in mind? The function must be installed in the code sheet of the tab on which you have the command button.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ' 027

    On Error Resume Next
    With Worksheets(Cells(3, "P").Value)
        .Cells(CLng(Cells(4, "M").Value), CLng(Cells(4, "N").Value)) _
              .Formula = Cells(4, "P").Formula
    End With
    If Err Then
        MsgBox "There is an error in the specs." & vbCr & _
               "Check the tab's name.", vbInformation, _
               "Execution suspended"
        Cells(3, "P").Select
    End If
End Sub
```